# Bootstrap Nav Bar Active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using the navbar from bootstrap however whenever I click on one of the page titles, the navbar doesn't highlight it to show that I'm on that page. For example, if I'm on the home page then the navbar looks like this:
[image]

However, if I click on `About`, I go to the About page but the navbar still looks like this:
[image]

How do I make it highlight the page it's on? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar). You need to apply `class="active"` to the `li` element that you want to be active. It is not handled automatically. You need to implement it however you see fit.

It could be either a JQuery solution or a server side solution. Either one could be more or less appropriate depending on the way your website is built.

Comment: from a good design and coding standpoint, which is better? Doing a jquery or php solution? Thanks for you help

Comment: Server side solution usually is more reliable, thus - more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MVC4, Razor and Bootstrap and ended up using a solution from coderwall.com (https://coderwall.com/p/hwtkng)

```
<li @if (@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") == "Home") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active");}>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
                    </li>
```

Comment: Good tip. I might add that if you, like me, need to check the action instead of controller the below snippet will do: `<li @if (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "Index") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active");}>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                <li @if (ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == "About") { @Html.AttributeEncode("class=active");}>@Html.ActionLink("About us", "About", "Home")</li>`